# I need to know what the resistance of the stator and rotor windings are

Tags: resistance, generator, alternator

How do I calculate the resistance value of an alternator stator?

- 2.5 kW
- 50 Hz
- 220 V
- 8.3 A
- 12 V

Comment: If the stator pulls 8.3A at 12VDC then Ohm’s law gives you the resistance.

Comment: What are the numbers you have given in your question related to regards the alternator? I see the question has now been reformatted by @JRE and now, it looks like a multiple-choice question whereas previously it didn't. Might I suggest there are some dangers in blindly reformatting a question that doesn't match you own expectations; trading meaning for neatness is never a good idea.

Comment: @Karman: "If the stator pulls 8.3A at 12VDC then Ohm’s law gives you the resistance" No it doesn't. You applied Ohm's law to a motor. Ohm's law only applies to resistors. A motor is not a resistor. Hence, Ohm's law doesn't apply to it. In _some_ motor types, a _stalled_  motor  acts like a resistor, and then you can apply Ohm's law. But the values OP provided are while running, not at stall, so, again, you can't use Ohm's law.

Comment: (For all google would tell, 12 V 8.3 A are DC, probably shared with an optional electric starter.)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know what the resistance of the stator and rotor windings are

1. Disconnect the alternator
2. Get a meter
3. Set it to Ohm
4. Connect the probes together
5. Note the reading: that's the resistance of the probes
6. Connect the probes to the winding
7. Note the reading: that's the resistance of the winding plus the probes
8. Subtract the two readings: that's the resistance of the winding

You can't calculate the resistance from the values you gave us because they are rated values for a rotating alternator under full load. They include the effect of EMF. The winding resistance can only be calculated, indirectly, when the alternator is stalled and there is no EMF. Or, as I suggested, when it's not in use, by measuring it directly.